# unexpected behavior of ssh in CentOS 6.x

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, centos6

I have a CentOS VM running as ec2 instance, I originally imported this VM to Amazon (the reason that I need to export it later on).

I have enabled log in using ssh keys and disabled password authentication, it was working good until yesterday where it suddenly started to ask me for password. I have the password so I am not locked out of the VM.

My problem that I am trying to get login via ssh keys but it is not working, I am getting

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I don't have experience in debugging sshd so I did basic testing to see the log, so I stopped sshd and run it as daemon on port 22

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 22
```

Then when I tried to connect to the VM using ssh keys it worked! I stopped it and started sshd as service and I got the same Permission Denied message above.

When I started sshd as daemon I got this when logged in using ssh keys (sshd log)

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='22'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 46.xx.xx.xx port 60823
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "46.xx.xx.xx"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: 01:03:92:98:97:af:7e:2b:45:bd:02:f7:0d:13:45:40
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for root from 46.xx.xx.xx port 60823 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: 01:03:92:98:97:af:7e:2b:45:bd:02:f7:0d:13:45:40
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for root from 46.248.215.245 port 60823 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: root has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support enabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 11 (0xb)
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 17 (0x11)
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

and the client side (my machine log) :

```
Ahmads-MacBook-Pro:brivolabs-sam-cs elkhawajah$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@xx.xx.xx.xx
Last login: Sat Feb  1 07:43:37 2014 from xx.xx.xx.xx
debug1: PAM: reinitializing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
Environment:
  LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
  USER=root
  LOGNAME=root
  HOME=/root
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
  MAIL=/var/mail/root
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=46.xx.xx.xx 60823 22
  SSH_CONNECTION=46.xx.xx.xx 60823 10.166.3.28 22
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
  TERM=xterm-256color
  SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
  SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
  SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
[root@ip-10-166-3-28 ~]#
```

Do you know how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm slightly confused about is that the client log you have shows you have successfully logged in. Are these logs from a successful or an unsuccessful login? If the former, we need the latter.

I'm partly guessing here but my educated guess is that this is the problem:
{code}
    debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
{code}

Every time I have problems with `ssh` the first thing I do is edit the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client to say:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

And add on the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
UseDNS no
```

I'm assuming here you don't actually want to use GSSAPI.

This speeds things up and appears to fix some issues at least for me.

Other standard checks are that your home directory is not writeable by anyone bar you, that `.ssh` is permission `0700`, and that the `authorized_keys` file is `0600` or `0644`. I don't think those are the issue here because you'd see different debug.

Comment: These are logs from successful login when running sshd as daemon, where can i find the log when running sshd as service ?

Comment: by this "Other standard checks are that your home directory is not writeable by anyone bar you" do you mean the /root folder permissions ? it is set to "dr-xr-x---.  10 root root  4096 Feb  1 06:53 root"

Comment: btw, I am trying to understand why it works when I run sshd as daemon while it won't work if I run it as service

Comment: First I would try to determine the exact command line used to launch `sshd` with `bash -x /etc/init.d/ssh start`. It might be a difference in the command lines used; and `bash -x` will print out every line run. Secondly, you can introduce debugging into `sshd` as run from the init script by putting `SSHDOPTS=-d` into `/etc/default/ssh` (or simply copying and modifying the init script). It should log to the normal place (`/var/log/auth.log` from memory).

Comment: this is the start log when running "bash -x service sshd start" https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5fuwy76xygljox/sshd1.rtf and this is the start log when starting using "bash -x /etc/init.d/sshd  start" https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mz4dutgu1a33gq/sshd2.rtf

Comment: Sorry I meant compare the output of `bash -x /etc/init.d/sshd start` with your command line. `service` will just call the former. Also, pastebin is bar better than dropbox for text. Anyway, `/etc/init.d/sshd/` seems to merely run `/usr/sbin/sshd` with no arguments. My `SSHDOPTS` thing was for debian/ubuntu (sorry). On Centos you want to edit `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` and put `OPTIONS=-d` in the file I think, to make it run in debug mode.